# Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" Malformed argument has embedded quote: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=

Tags: java, intellij-idea, weblogic

ERROR: **Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe" (in directory "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.3\compile-server"): Malformed argument has embedded quote: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=**

I keep getting this error everytime I Redeploy my Spring Boot project via weblogic server in IntelliJ IDE.
The first time I deploy, everything works just fine. But when I Redeploy the project in order to effect new changes, this error comes up.

My Tools:

1. IntelliJ IDEA 2020.3 (Ultimate Edition)
2. WebLogic Server Version: 12.2.1.3.0
3. Windows 10
4. Java (JDK) version "1.8.0_202"
5. Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-b08)

What I have Tried:

1. I only have one installed JDK and JRE version: 1.8.0_202 installed on my PC
2. Deleted javaws.exe, javaw.exe & java.exe fields from my Sys32 Folder (A Googled Solution)
3. Able to view my Java version on cmd when I run: java -version
4. Path to my jdk is correct: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe
5. IntelliJ is correctly pointing to my JDK folder [JDK Linked to My IntelliJ IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMozb.png)
6. My Weblogic configurations look just fine: [My Weblogic configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg4b8.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also encountered the same problem.
The reason is that I installed the FindBugs plugin.
You can try to add the following line of parameters to the idea64.exe.vmoptions.

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot. Took me some time to find where those vm options were though.

Answer (score 0):

For those that need help finding the VM options in the IDE. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1 by the way.

On the IDE Toolbar at the top -> click HELP -> Edit Custom VM Options...

Then add this VM option at the bottom (uncluding the hyphen '-' symbol):

```
-Djdk.lang.Process.allowAmbiguousCommands=true
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure this will be helpful to someone.